# How to count word frequency from a list in the whole file?

Tags: python, list, nlp, word-frequency

I have a file with three columns (separated by \t; first column is word, second is lemma, third is tag). Some lines only consist of dot or comma.

```
<doc n=1 id="CMP/94/10">
<head p="80%">
Customs customs tag1
union   union   tag2
in  in  tag3
danger  danger  tag4
of  of  tag5
the the tag6
</head>
<head p="80%">
New new tag7
restrictions    restriction tag8
in  in  tag3
the the tag6
.
Hi  hi  tag8
```

Let's say the user searches lemma "in". I want frequency of "in" and frequency of lemmas before and after "in". So I want frequency of "union", "danger", "restriction" and "the" in the **whole** corpus. The result should be:

```
union    1  
danger   1 
restriction    1  
the    2
```

**How do I do that?** I tried to use `lemma_counter = {}` but it does not work.

I am not experienced in python language, so please correct me if I got anything wrong.

```
c = open("corpus.vert")

corpus = []

for line in c:
    if not line.startswith("<"):
        corpus.append(line)

lemma = raw_input("Lemma you are looking for: ")

counter = 0
lemmas_before_after = []       
for i in range(len(corpus)):
    parsed_line = corpus[i].split("\t")
    if len(parsed_line) > 1:
        if parsed_line[1] == lemma: 
            counter += 1    #this counts lemma frequency


            new_list = []

            for j in range(i-1, i+2):
                if j < len(corpus) and j >= 0:
                    parsed_line_with_context = corpus[j].split("\t")
        found_lemma = parsed_line_with_context[0].replace("\n","")
        if len(parsed_line_with_context) > 1:
            if lemma != parsed_line_with_context[1].replace("\n",""):                        
            lemmas_before_after.append(found_lemma)        
        else:
            lemmas_before_after.append(found_lemma)                  

print "list of lemmas ", lemmas_before_after


lemma_counter = {}
for i in range(len(corpus)):
    for lemma in lemmas_before_after:
        if parsed_line[1] == lemma:
            if lemma in lemma_counter:
                lemma_counter[lemma] += 1
            else:
                lemma_counter[lemma] = 1

print lemma_counter


fA = counter
print "lemma frequency: ", fA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you 80% of the way.

```
# Let's use some useful pieces of the awesome standard library
from collections import namedtuple, Counter

# Define a simple structure to hold the properties of each entry in corpus
CorpusEntry = namedtuple('CorpusEntry', ['word', 'lemma', 'tag'])

# Use a context manager ("with...") to automatically close the file when we no
# longer need it
with open('corpus.vert') as c:
    corpus = []
    for line in c:
        if len(line.strip()) > 1 and not line.startswith('<'):
            # Remove the newline character and split at tabs
            word, lemma, tag = line.strip().split('\t')
            # Put the obtained values in the structure
            entry = CorpusEntry(word, lemma, tag)
            # Put the structure in the corpus list
            corpus.append(entry)

# It's practical to wrap the counting in a function
def get_frequencies(lemma):
    # Create a set of indices at which the lemma occurs in corpus. We use a
    # set because it is more efficient for the next part, checking if some
    # index is in this set
    lemma_indices = set()
    # Loop over corpus without manual indexing; enumerate provides information
    # about the current index and the value (some CorpusEntry added earlier).
    for index, entry in enumerate(corpus):
        if entry.lemma == lemma:
            lemma_indices.add(index)

    # Now that we have the indices at which the lemma occurs, we can loop over
    # corpus again and for each entry check if it is either one before or
    # one after the lemma. If so, add the entry's lemma to a new set.
    related_lemmas = set()
    for index, entry in enumerate(corpus):
        before_lemma = index+1 in lemma_indices
        after_lemma = index-1 in lemma_indices
        if before_lemma or after_lemma:
            related_lemmas.add(entry.lemma)

    # Finally, we need to count the number of occurrences of those related
    # lemmas
    counter = Counter()
    for entry in corpus:
        if entry.lemma in related_lemmas:
            counter[entry.lemma] += 1

    return counter

print get_frequencies('in')
# Counter({'the': 2, 'union': 1, 'restriction': 1, 'danger': 1})
```

It could be written more concisely (below), and the algorithm could be improved as well, though it's still O(n); the point was to make it understandable.

For those interested:

```
with open('corpus.vert') as c:
    corpus = [CorpusEntry(*line.strip().split('\t')) for line in c
              if len(line.strip() > 1) and not line.startswith('<')]

def get_frequencies(lemma):
    lemma_indices = {index for index, entry in enumerate(corpus)
                     if entry.lemma == lemma}
    related_lemmas = {entry.lemma for index, entry in enumerate(corpus)
                      if lemma_indices & {index+1, index-1}}
    return Counter(entry.lemma for entry in corpus
                   if entry.lemma in related_lemmas)
```

And here's a more procedural style that works about three times as fast:

```
def get_frequencies(lemma):
    counter = Counter()
    related_lemmas = set()
    for index, entry in enumerate(corpus):
        counter[entry.lemma] += 1
        if entry.lemma == lemma:
            if index > 0:
                related_lemmas.add(corpus[index-1].lemma)
            if index < len(corpus)-1:
                related_lemmas.add(corpus[index+1].lemma)
    return {lemma: frequency for lemma, frequency in counter.iteritems()
            if lemma in related_lemmas}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I found out, my file is not exactly what I expected though. Some lines consists of only a dot or comma, so the tuple won't work for them. I tried this: `if not line.startswith('<'):`
    `if len(line) > 1:` but it still gives me an error "need more than 1 value to unpack".

Comment: @halik You have to take into account that every `line`, before it is added to `corpus`, also contains the new line character (`\n`), so initially every `line` has a length > 1. I adjusted my answer.